# MongoDB - add a new property at the end of a collection record

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection called `answers` which has dozens of documents in it.

I would like to add a new property called `archive` at the end of each document in this collection.

Final state of the collection record should be like shown below where `archive` property is added to each document.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b30b90f40d08d8871c2d2fd"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2018-06-25T09:42:39.870Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2018-09-17T08:30:04.300Z"),
    "status" : "overdue",
    "archive" : ""
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try

```
db.answers.updateMany({},{$set:{archive:"1"}})
```

Additional references are [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/)

Comment: Great! That will update all records in the collection with new property, which is fine. Is there a way to check whether archive property already exists? If not exists, add it to the document.

Comment: This will add the archive property whether it exists of not.

Comment: as per the documentation , you can use upsert parameter to control this behaviour. Check the link please

Comment: anytime :) glad that I could help

Comment: @Satya - Conversely, is there a way to remove the archive property from all documents in one statement?

Comment: @Satya - Excellent Satya!